# Could someone show me how this is implemented in main()? (question on void pointers)

Tags: c++, c

I got the below snippet from Algorithms in a nut shell

```
void sortPointers (void **ar, int n,
int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *)) {

int j;

for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
   int i = j-1;
   void *value = ar[j];
   while (i >= 0 && cmp (ar[i], value) > 0) {
   ar[i+1] = ar[i];
   i--;
}

ar[i+1] = value;
}
}
```

[https://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Nutshell-OReilly-George-Heineman/dp/059651624X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059651624X)

They do not provide the main() implementation of

```
sortPointers
```

so i have some problems figuring out what does **ar do

when i attempted to do a test code on

```
**arrPtr = x
```

it returns the error that you cannot cast void ** on a int *.

this surprises me as the book clearly says you feed an array into the function.

```
int main()
{
    var x[3] = { 2 , 4 , 3};

    void **arrPtr = x[0];



    return 0;
}
```

a side question as well.

```
void *value = ar[j];
```

is this a unneeded step? the CMP function was able to take ar[i] as a argument, shouldnt it be able to take ar[j] as is?

Comment: `ar` is an array of pointers.

Comment: the type of `arrPtr` is `void**` the `*` in pointer variables can be placed next to the name of the variable or the type, but either way it's part of the type. So that means this is a "pointer to pointer"

Comment: hi both.. a side question as well.

void *value = ar[j];

is this a unneeded step? the CMP function was able to take ar[i] as a argument, shouldnt it be able to take ar[j] as is?

Comment: @tkausl could you illustrate that as a main() implementation? I think i am having problems visualizing that.

Comment: what is the main() implementation supposed to do?

Comment: @ChrisRollins sorry my language is not the most clear.

I think what I am trying to ask if that if someone could show me how this function is implemented.

BEING 

int main()
{
    sortPointers(array, n, cmp)

}

how does the above look like in a proper implementation.

as of now I only have the function, which is really really confusing on visualizing the different parameters/arguments.

Comment: `main()` needs something like `int* ar[] = { new int{2}, new int{4}, new int{3} };` to sort, then you need a compare/less function like `[](const void* pa, const void* pb) { int a = *pa, b = *pb; return a < b ? -1 : a == b ? 0 : 1; }` (shown as a lambda).  More generally, if you want to learn C++ and not C, get another book.  C++ has templates to provide type-safe and more understandable code instead of this C-style hackery.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Thank you that was exactly what I am trying to request for .

its a pity the book only have C implementation that reads like abstract art

Comment: @jamesdlin sorry fixed it, i was having problems with uploading my question

Comment: @youcantcme: oh - you'll actually need an explicit cast: `int a = *static_cast<const int*>(pa), ...`    I'm afraid I can't recommend a text book - both off topic and it's been so long since I was learning anything like this I wouldn't know which book was worthwhile.  I think there's a C++ book recommendation list linked off the S.O. C++ page, or google-able.

Comment: @TonyDelroy 

I just tried 

    int* ar[] = { new int{2}, new int{4}, new int{3} };

the compiler refuses to build.

It only builds with 

    void* ar[] = { new int{2}, new int{4}, new int{3} };

Comment: @TonyDelroy that static_cast thing is new to me. I will read up on it. Thank you for the book recommendation as well.

i am only tackling C because this book is a great reference for algos (less technical in math areas so that it is actionable while remaining readable). its the C implementation that makes it tough .


i primarily use C#
thanks man

Comment: FWIW, `static_cast` above is a more restrictive alternative to the C style `*(const int*)pa`, which means *"hey, pa actually points at an integer constant, dereference the pointer value and access the integer"*.  Without a cast, the compiler won't know what type of data the `void*` is pointing too - that's kind of the point of using `void`: type erasure.

Comment: @TonyDelroy thanks for that tip mate. appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to learn C or C++? These languages are very different, but they have enough in common to cause major confusion in novices when approached simultaneously.

Comment: Note: About the only time you want to use a `void` pointer in C++ is when you have to work with an old program or a program written in C.Virtually every other case is handles with templates or inheritance. Learn what you can from C programming resources, but know that there may be solution that takes better advantage of C++.

Answer (score 3):

In C we have the function `qsort` which is a generic function to sort arrays. It can sort all kind of arrays (e.g. arrays of int, arrays of double and even arrays of custom structs). All it requires is that the user provide a "compare" function for comparing two elements.

The `sortPointers` seems to be pretty much the same **except** it does **not** sort arrays of elements but instead sorts an array of pointers to elements.

As far a I can see the idea is to use it like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    int* pa = (int*)a;
    int* pb = (int*)b;
    if (*pa > *pb) return 1;
    if (*pa < *pb) return -1;
    return 0;
}

void sortPointers (void **ar, int n,
                   int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *)) 
{
    int j;

    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
       int i = j-1;
       void *value = ar[j];
       while (i >= 0 && cmp (ar[i], value) > 0) {
           ar[i+1] = ar[i];
           i--;
        }

        ar[i+1] = value;
    }
}

void pp(int **ar, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
        printf("Address %p holds the value %p and points to %d, i.e. arr[%d] points to %d\n", (void*)(&ar[i]), (void*)ar[i], *ar[i], i, *ar[i]);
}

#define ELEM 3

int main(void)
{
    int* arr[3];
    for(int i=0; i<ELEM; ++i) arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *arr[0] = 5;
    *arr[1] = 8;
    *arr[2] = 2;

    pp(arr, ELEM);
    sortPointers((void**)arr, ELEM, cmp);
    printf("------------------------\n");
    pp(arr, ELEM);

    for(int i=0; i<ELEM; ++i) free(arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address 0x7fff9a7d0270 holds the value 0xeeb010 and points to 5, i.e. arr[0] points to 5
Address 0x7fff9a7d0278 holds the value 0xeeb030 and points to 8, i.e. arr[1] points to 8
Address 0x7fff9a7d0280 holds the value 0xeeb050 and points to 2, i.e. arr[2] points to 2
------------------------
Address 0x7fff9a7d0270 holds the value 0xeeb050 and points to 2, i.e. arr[0] points to 2
Address 0x7fff9a7d0278 holds the value 0xeeb010 and points to 5, i.e. arr[1] points to 5
Address 0x7fff9a7d0280 holds the value 0xeeb030 and points to 8, i.e. arr[2] points to 8
```

However, the whole function seems to be a waste of time. **The standard `qsort` can do this for you so why write a special function?** As written above `qsort` can sort all kind of arrays so it can also sort an array of pointers. The compare function just needs to be a bit different. Simply use `qsort` like:

```
// Compare function
int cmp_qsort(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    int** pa = (int**)a;
    int** pb = (int**)b;
    if (**pa > **pb) return 1;
    if (**pa < **pb) return -1;
    return 0;
}

// Call from main like:
qsort(arr, ELEM, sizeof(int*), cmp_qsort);
```

The output will be the same (except for the address that change every time you run it) and you don't need a custom sort function like `sortPointers`.